# How to remove the comma in facet labels when ".multi_line = FALSE"

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap(c("cyl", "drv"), labeller = labeller(.multi_line = FALSE))
```

I would like to replace the comma with space in labels.

[image: Code output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mpg$label <- paste(mpg$cyl, mpg$drv)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap(~label)
```

[image: Final plots]

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this -

```
 ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap(c("cyl", "drv"), labeller = function (labels) {
      labels <- lapply(labels, as.character)
      a <-  do.call(paste, c(labels, list(sep = ",")))
      list(gsub("\\,"," ",a))
    })
```

**Note**- We can pass any custom function by using this method.

**Output-**

[image: Output]